# Java read from URL stream working selectively

Tags: java, urlconnection

**Summary**: Sample Java code that reads over a URLConnection reads only certain URLs, not others.

**Details**: I have this sample Java code that I am using to read over a URLConnection.  When the URL is "http://www.example.com", the code reads the page content without any issues.  However, if the URL is "http://www.cnn.com", the page content is not read

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader inputStream = null;
        try {
            String urlStr = "http://www.cnn.com"; // Does not work
//          urlStr = "http://www.example.com"; // **Works if this line is uncommented**

            URL url = new URL(urlStr);

            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            String textLine = null;
            while((textLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(textLine);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the two assignments to `url`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  Thanks for pointing out.  It has been fixed now.

Comment: This article suggests it's by design. https://www.cs.mun.ca/java-api-1.5/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/upgrade-guide/article-17.html.  I tried some other SO suggestions for `setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)` and they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CNN redirects from http to https but your call doesn't follow redirects. You are getting a 307 with an empty body so the readline results in a null and your loop is skipped. Try with https for CNN.

Comment: Kindly suggest the most elegant way to handle redirects so that the code can seamlessly handle both http and https.

Comment: Redirects are followed by default.

Comment: @user207421 No, they don't appear to be followed by default, at least not with HTTP --> HTTPS on Java 8u181 nor using `setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)`.  This article is dated (Java 5) but may still be valid: https://www.cs.mun.ca/java-api-1.5/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/upgrade-guide/article-17.html